# What is a normal heap growth when using the allocation instrument?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, instruments

I am using the "mark generation" button of the allocation instrument.
Every snapshot generation adds about 200 KB to the growth column.

I can't find anything suspicious so could it be that the growth is due to the system libs or maybe some core data caches?

Comment: also any advice on learning how to interpret the overwhelming amount of statistic columns (allocation instrument) would be great? any tutorials or blogs? I find that the apple user guide is a little bit more a reference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that system libraries generates some new MBs to the system heap. What is more, they should be doing this! And you cannot do anything abut that...

You could try looking at this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode) which I was inspecting a few days ago to give myself a easy-start with **Instruments**.